# Comparator for use with sort

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ and want to implement something similar: I defined a function `clauseComparator` which is like `myfunc` given in the example in the link provided.

```
bool QueryEvaluatorPrivate::clauseComparator(QueryClause cl1, QueryClause cl2) {
    int priority1 = clausePriority(cl1), 
        priority2 = clausePriority(cl2);
    return priority1 < priority2;
}
```

and I used it like:

```
sort(clauses.begin(), clauses.end(), clauseComparator);
```

But VS complains:

```
Error   4   error C3867: 'QueryEvaluatorPrivate::clauseComparator': function call missing argument list; use '&QueryEvaluatorPrivate::clauseComparator' to create a pointer to member   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\query\query evaluator\queryevaluator.cpp  138
Error   5   error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\query\query evaluator\queryevaluator.cpp  138
```

Firstly whats wrong (missing arg list)? I tried following the suggestion given in the error to add `&` and ended up with

```
Error   4   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression    h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\query\query evaluator\queryevaluator.cpp  138
Error   5   error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\code\source\query\query evaluator\queryevaluator.cpp  138
```

Whats wrong here? In my understanding, it should pass a function pointer which I understand should be accepted by `sort` too?

Comment: I don't think you can use a member function of a class as a comparator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your member function static in order to be accessible by `sort`.
In your class header, please declare it as such:

`static bool QueryEvaluatorPrivate::clauseComparator(const QueryClause & cl1, const QueryClause & cl2);`

There is no need to use `bind`, as your comparator most likely (or shouldn't) have any need to access class members.

Comment: static? no need, it might be just global function

Comment: No need to pollute the global namespace unless you have good reason. Qualified methods provide context, so I recommend static member comparator.

Comment: this is not "need", you might want to change this into "can"

Comment: another issue is that it will be passed as const referrences so than we need also: QueryClause(const QueryClause &qc)
    {
    } otherwise error

Answer (score 1):

You can't use member functions for this. Make `clauseComparator` a free function or a `static` member function.

Your comparator should also take arguments by const reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `std::bind` to bind the member function to `std::sort` because you otherwise can't bind a member function to `std::sort`

so it would like this:

```
 sort(clauses.begin(), clauses.end(), std::bind(&QueryEvaluatorPrivate::clauseComparator, instance, args));
```

Answer (score 0):

because std::sort (it is this sort, right?) is declared as

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);


template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```

so function comp has to be:

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments,
>   and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates
>   whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go
>   before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines. The
>   function shall not modify any of its arguments. This can either be a
>   function pointer or a function object.

so please make it global function

```
bool myfunction (QueryClause q1,QueryClause q2) { return (//condition); }
```

or declare functor:

```
struct myclass {
  bool operator() (QueryClause q1,QueryClause q2) { return (//condition again);}
} myobjectcomparator;
```

and you need:

```
QueryClause(const QueryClause &qc) { }
```

to guarantee constness